# Select the max value along with a corresponding title?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables there were created and populated like this:

```
create table booklist(title varchar(20), bookid char(2) PRIMARY KEY);
create table numberofcopies (bookid char(2) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES booklist(bookid), numcopies int);

insert into booklist VALUES ('book 1', 1), ('book 2', 2);
insert into numberofcopies VALUES (1, 5), (2, 10);
```

What I am trying to do is get the max value, in this case '10' from `id#2`, then say its corresponding title, "book 2." What my query instead returns is a list of all of the books, rather than just the book with the max value. How would I go about doing this? My SQL query so far:

```
SELECT MAX(numCopies), title AS Title
FROM numberofcopies JOIN booklist ON numberofcopies.bookid=booklist.bookid
GROUP BY Title;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the book with most copies, you can just join, order by and limit:

```
select top (1) bl.*, noc.numcopies
from booklist bl
inner join numberofcopies noc on noc.bookid = bl.bookid
order by noc.numcopies desc
```

If you want to allow top ties, you can use `top (1) with ties` instead.

---

**Edit**: if you *do* want `max()`, one approach is to join, then filter with a correlated subquery that gets the maximum `numcopies` from `numberofcopies`.

```
select bl.*, noc.numberofcopies
from booklist bl
inner join numberofcopies noc on noc.bookid = bl.bookid
where noc.numcopies = (select max(numcopies) from numberofcopies)
```

Note that this requires one more scan on `numberofcopies`, so this really is less efficient than the first solution.

Comment: Is it possible to do what I want to do with the max clause? That is partially what the assignment wants me to do.

Comment: @howimetmyself: using `max()` will be more convoluted, for no value added. As I understand your question, `top 1` really is the correct approach. But, ok, I added another query to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add after `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
ORDER BY numCopies DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The query will order values from biggest to lowest. Limiting by 1 the result, you will have the MAX value.